# Postgres Vacuum in Function

Tags: postgresql, performance, vacuum, postgresql-performance

After *googleing* a bit, it's plainly clear you cannot run vacuum from a function:

[Postgres mailing - Vacuum behaviour in plpgsql function](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/C34466F5BBA39949A8F5C180022EC206484668%40zaq-msg-03.corp.zaq.com)

> You can't run VACUUM from inside a function because of memory-management
>   limitations.  In current sources there is an error check to prevent you
>   from trying.

[Stackoverflow - VACUUM cannot be executed from a function or multi-command string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21763164/vacuum-cannot-be-executed-from-a-function-or-multi-command-string)

> Once the data is loaded, I would like to "vacuum analyze" the affected tables, both to recover the space from the deleted records and to accurately reflect the new contents. [...] When I run this, I get:
>
> `ERROR:  VACUUM cannot be executed from a function or multi-command string`

But I really need to "automatically" run vacuum whenever a certain function is run: this function updates a lot of records (if not all of them) so the number of dead rows increases quite fast and other query performance decrease a lot.
The problem is the function is called from another program. 
Any best practice?
Should I manually add the vacuum statement into a separeted piece of code after the function execution, someting like

`sql = SELECT my_function()
<program.execute(sql)>
sql = VACUUM [FULL | ANALYZE] my_updated_table
<program.execute(sql)>`

Comment: How often is the function run?  Are you able to go for a `VACUUM FULL`, exclusively locking the table for the duration?  If there's a large number of dead rows, can you instead use `CLUSTER`?

Comment: Well, the function is run, more or less, twice a week.
I think I can go for a `VACUUM FULL` exclusive lock.
Yes, there's a large number of dead rows (last time 50% ~ 4GB). I've tried to manually run cluster (from the client PgAdmin III) but I get the error

`ERROR:  there is no previously clustered index for table "my_table"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/routine-vacuuming.html) page:

> **Tip:** Plain VACUUM may not be satisfactory when a table contains large numbers of dead row versions as a result of massive update or delete activity. If you have such a table and you need to reclaim the excess disk space it occupies, *you will need to use VACUUM FULL, or alternatively CLUSTER* or one of the table-rewriting variants of ALTER TABLE. These commands rewrite an entire new copy of the table and build new indexes for it. All these options require exclusive lock. Note that they also temporarily use extra disk space approximately equal to the size of the table, since the old copies of the table and indexes can't be released until the new ones are complete.

If you can't get away with an exclusive lock on the table, you also might be fine with a simple `ANALYZE <tablename>;`, as that will only take a read lock and should update the statistics for the table and reduce ( if not entirely eliminate ) performance degradation for the other queries.  Then you can let the regular autovacuum daemon do its thing ( or whatever your current custom vacuum solution might be ) normally.

If your table doesn't even have a clustered index, you will first need to do an `ALTER TABLE <tablename> CLUSTER ON <indexname>;`.  You should probably have some kind of clustered index anyway: Having a massive heap table and poor performance against it often goes hand in hand.

As far as best practices go, I would be highly inclined to recommend the `ANALYZE` approach insofar as doing an automatic statistics update is by far preferable to an automatic index rebuild or virtually any form of `VACUUM FULL` being run without an admin actively watching it.